# Handling Exceptions in Java - How to give user another chance?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Hey guys so i've been trying to answer this question for hours:
    Write a program that asks the user to input a set of floating-point values. When the
user enters a value that is not a number, give the user a second chance to enter the
value. After two chances, quit reading input. Add all correctly specified values and
print the sum when the user is done entering data. Use exception handling to detect
improper inputs.

I've tried a few different things but i always have the same problem. Once something that   isn't a number is given as input, the program outputs the message prompting for another input however the chance is not given, that is to say after 1 incorrect input it prints that message and jumps straight to printing the sum. The best i could do is below i'm just not sure how to approach this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class q6{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean firstChance = true;
    boolean secondChance = true;
    double sum = 0;
    while (secondChance){
        try{
            while (firstChance){
                try{
                    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
                    double input = in.nextDouble();
                    sum = sum + input;
                }
                catch (InputMismatchException ex){
                    firstChance = false;
                }
            System.out.print("Please enter a number to continue or something else to terminate: ");
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            sum = sum + input;
            firstChance = true;
            }
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e){
            secondChance = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("The sum of the entered values is " + sum);
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of reading a `double`, read a `String` and use `Double.parseDouble(String)`. Also, if your `firstChance` is `true` after the `try-catch` block, you should break the `while-loop`s.

Comment: looking at your question you seem to know the logic but it is not reflected in the code. I would suggest dry run this code with a test input and try finding out the issue yourself.you just need to make sure that your program goes back to the initial prompt after giving the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i'm just not sure how to approach this problem

Pseudocode could be as follows:

```
BEGIN

    MAX_INPUT = 2;
    i = 0;

    WHILE i < MAX_INPUT

        TRY
            num = GET_NUM();
        CATCH
            continue;
        FINALLY
            i++

    END WHILE

END
```

Comment: *Use exception handling to detect improper inputs* I guess you forgot to read that part of the question.

Comment: Thanks this worked, along with the other suggestions of re-initializing the scanner after an exception was caught.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **break** your `while` loop when you encounter a *"bad"* input. Then, you'll need to set `firstChance` to **true** again, so you can access the second `while`, you also will need a counter that counts the number of the attempts (I named it `chances`):

```
int chances = 0;
while (secondChance){
    firstChance = true;
    try{
        while (firstChance){
            try{
                System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
                double input = in.nextDouble();
                sum = sum + input;
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException ex){
                chances ++;
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                firstChance = false;
            }
            if(!firstChance && chances < 2)
                break;
            if(chances >= 2) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a number to continue or something else to terminate: ");
                double input = in.nextDouble();
                sum = sum + input;
                firstChance = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e){
    secondChance = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not the desired working of the program. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parsing of input to double is not successful, the scanner does not go past the given input. From [javadoc Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29)

> Scans the next token of the input as a double. This method will throw
>   InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a
>   valid double value. **If the translation is successful, the scanner
>   advances past the input that matched**.

Since the translation is not successful, it does not advance. So, in the catch block you could call [in.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) to skip the token.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integer counter instead of the boolean variables firstChance and secondChance and do something like:

```
int attempts = 0;
while(attempts < 2) {
    try {
        //Get user input - possible exception point
        //Print sum
    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
        attempts++;
        //Continue?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class q6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double inputNumber, sum = 0.0;
        int correctCount = 0, wrongCount = 0;

        while(wrongCount <=1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a numeric floating value:");
            try {
                inputNumber = in.nextDouble();
                correctCount++;
                sum += inputNumber;
                if(correctCount >= 2)
                    break;
            } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                wrongCount++;
                in = new Scanner(System.in);
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, in order to not deal with Scanner wrong read, it would be better to use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) and read the data as `String`, then try to parse it as `double` using [`Double#parseDouble(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) since this method already throws [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) and you can handle this error. Also, it would be better that your code could handle more than 1 request (if your teacher or somebody else asks to do this):

```
final int REQUEST_TIMES = 2;
double sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= REQUEST_TIMES; i++) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            if (i < REQUEST_TIMES) {
                System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Please enter a number to continue or something else to terminate: ");
            }
            String stringInput = in.nextLine();
            double input = Double.parseDouble(stringInput);
            sum += input;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println("You haven't entered a valid number.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is to read the input once, if it is correct then display the sum, else read the input again and display the sum if the input is correct.

```
public class q6 {

    static int trial = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double sum = 0;

        while (trial <= 2) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                trial++;
                System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
                double input = in.nextDouble();
                sum = sum + input;
                trial=3;
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                trial++;
                if (trial == 4){
                    System.out.println("You have entered wrong values twice");
                }
            }
        }
        if (trial <= 3){
            System.out.print("The sum of the entered values is " + sum);
        }
    }
```

The above program is just a rough idea, you can improve this to adapt to your need.

Comment: For some reason, initializing the scanner outside the loop won't work with multiple attempts !